# Twilio node api: no video portion?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to build a back-end service to query for room status in a twilio video conversation.

Following this example:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#get-by-unique-name

The client created from the constructor doesn't have a video member, so the API isn't working.  I get 'client.video' as null, so can't call any of the client.video.XXX functions.

Using twilio version 2.11.4.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio Video REST API was not supported in the [Twilio package for Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) in version 2. Please upgrade to version 3 to use the Video functions. There is an [upgrade guide](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/wiki/Node-Version-3.x-Upgrade-Guide) if you have other functions built using the version 2 package.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I didn't see there was a version 3 yet.  I did discover the REST APIs, though.